# Rails exception; is my app vulnerable? <script>alert("xssvuln")</script>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, xss

I have [exception notification](https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification) installed on my app, and I got a few of these notifications last night:

An ActionView::Template::Error occurred in courses#online:

```
  PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "<script>alert("xssvuln")</script>"
LINE 1: ..."."class_type" = 'online' AND (content_areas.id = '<script>a...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "courses"."id" AS t0_r0, "courses"."title" AS t0_r1, "courses"."description" AS t0_r2, "courses"."certificate_note" AS t0_r3, "courses"."note" AS t0_r4, "courses"."ceu" AS t0_r5, "courses"."created_at" AS t0_r6, "courses"."updated_at" AS t0_r7, "courses"."slug" AS t0_r8, "courses"."old_id" AS t0_r9, "courses"."active" AS t0_r10, "courses"."sap_qualifying" AS t0_r11, "courses"."sap_renewing" AS t0_r12, "courses"."sae_qualifying" AS t0_r13, "courses"."sae_renewing" AS t0_r14, "content_areas"."id" AS t1_r0, "content_areas"."name" AS t1_r1, "content_areas"."created_at" AS t1_r2, "content_areas"."updated_at" AS t1_r3, "content_areas"."old_id" AS t1_r4 FROM "courses" INNER JOIN "course_classes" ON "course_classes"."course_id" = "courses"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "course_content_areas" ON "course_content_areas"."course_id" = "courses"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "content_areas" ON "content_areas"."id" = "course_content_areas"."content_area_id" WHERE "courses"."active" = 't' AND "cours
 e_classes"."active" = 't' AND "course_classes"."class_type" = 'online' AND (content_areas.id = '<script>alert("xssvuln")</script>')  ORDER BY "courses"."title" ASC
  app/views/courses/online.html.erb:17:in `_app_views_courses_online_html_erb___2231748092449029729_69943584017620'


-------------------------------
Request:
-------------------------------

  * URL        : https://www.my_app.org/online-courses?=%3Cscript%3Ealert(%22xssvuln%22)%3C/script%3E&content_area=%3Cscript%3Ealert(%22xssvuln%22)%3C/script%3E&search=%3Cscript%3Ealert(%22xssvuln%22)%3C/script%3E&utf8=%3Cscript%3Ealert(%22xssvuln%22)%3C/script%3E
  * HTTP Method: GET
  * IP address : 184.154.139.18
  * Parameters : {"content_area"=>"<script>alert(\"xssvuln\")</script>", "search"=>"<script>alert(\"xssvuln\")</script>", "utf8"=>"<script>alert(\"xssvuln\")</script>", "controller"=>"courses", "action"=>"online"}
  * Timestamp  : 2017-10-28 05:09:26 UTC
  * Server : localhost
  * Rails root : /home/deployer/my_app/releases/20171026113054
  * Process: 25937
```

It looks to me like the sql was indeed injected though the query actual failed. This is a problem right? Also, what about the `<script>alert("xssvuln")</script>` is that code that live somewhere in a template or some of my html?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like someone is checking if your website is Cross-site scripting (XSS) vulnerable or not.
More specifically someone has tried 'Reflected XSS', and alert(\"xssvuln\") was passed as the search Parameter but luckily you were using the parameter as integer which caused the exception.